# STM32 Trigger ADC by a Timer

Tags: stm32, adc

I have a STM32F722RC and would like to trigger the ADC2 over the PWM timer TIM2. The ADC2 has a external trigger conversion source of "Timer 2 Capture Compare 2 event" and "Timer 2 Trigger Out event" and I use channel 1-3 for PWM and would like to use channel 4 for triggering of the ADC2.

The thing is, when I use "Timer 2 Capture Compare 2 event", only channel 2 can trigger the ADC2, which makes totally sense (compare 2 event), but is it possible to trigger it from the channel 4, since my PCB has already connected channel 1-3 for PWM.

[image]

The other source "Timer 2 Trigger Out event" seems also only to trigger from channel 2 and I don't know why this is the case. Is it possible to trigger the ADC2 from TIM2 from channel 4 on a STM32F722RC?

Datasheet:
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f722ic.pdf

Ref Manual:
https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00305990-stm32f72xxx-and-stm32f73xxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

**Edit:** Here is my current implementation, but the ADC2 is not triggered by a OC4REF trigger event:

ADC Init:

```
  hadc2.Instance = ADC2;
  hadc2.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV2; /* Choose as low as possible --> more samples --> better accuracy --> Runs with 50MHz*/
  hadc2.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc2.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_ENABLE;
  hadc2.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc2.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc2.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T2_TRGO;
  hadc2.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc2.Init.NbrOfConversion = 2;
  hadc2.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc2.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
```

TIM2 Init:

```
  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_CENTERALIGNED2; //TIM_COUNTERMODE_CENTERALIGNED2
  htim2.Init.Period = SVPWM_CNTR_MAX;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE; //Preloading is extremly important --> shadow register to apply PWM only after the next update event

  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_OC4REF;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
```

**Edit 2:** Ok I already got it, I don't need to start channel 4, just the trigger output and then TIM2->CCR4 needs to be set accordingly. If then the timer counts to TIM2->CCR4, the trigger output triggers the ADC sampling.